# JUnit - IllegalArgumentException.class failes?

Tags: java, eclipse, unit-testing, testing, junit

I have created an extremely simple junit test, which creates a null product in the product table in the db.

```
@Test(expected = IllegalArgumentException.class)
public void testCreate_NULL() {
    Product p = null;
    createProduct(p);
}
```

but when I do the junit test it turns blue.

btw. other tests like creating a product, deleting ect. are all green...

I appreciate your answer!!!

PS.: I am using hsql db!

PPS.: The error is:

> java.lang.AssertionError: Expected exception:
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException    at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.statements.ExpectException.evaluate(ExpectException.java:35)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:30)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:263)    at
>   org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:68)
>     at
>   org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)  at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)     at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)  at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)

UPDATE:

my createProduct Method justs inserts a product into the db and before it checks:

```
    if(p==null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("null objects impossible");
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps it's throwing `NullReferenceException` instead of `IllegalArgumentException`? You should be able to see in the test failure details.

It's fairly hard to diagnose this without any indication of what's in the `createProduct` method.

Comment: my createProduct Method just inserts an argument via INSERT into the db, it doesn`t do anything more...

Comment: @maximus: Well apparently it does argument validation too... please post the whole method, or a short but complete program which demonstrates the problem.

Comment: ok got the mistake!!! The problem was that I had used exception handling even in my service layer and therefore I got an Exception back instead of an IllegalArgumentException!!! btw thanks for your help Mr Skeet!!!